# iOS Implementing Retina Graphics

Tags: ios, retina-display

When in storyboard, or code, do I use the @2x images or the normal ones in the image/background fields? In other words, does it upscale small graphics or downscale the large ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use the @2x but always refer to the smaller resolution. iOS will choose the @2x version when it is appropriate.

Comment: Great that's what I thought but I was just checking. Thanks.